# Plotting matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I begin with matplotlib and subplots. Could you tell me how to assign the 2 plots generated from this code in 2 columns:

```
# Bar Plot for Firm Performance
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6, 4))
title = fig.suptitle("Firm performance", fontsize=14)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, wspace=0.3)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)

dfSPSSactive['Q7_12_1'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
dfSPSSactive['Q7_12_2'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar', color='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass `ax` parameter to [**`pandas.DataFrame.plot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize = (6, 4))
title = fig.suptitle("Firm performance", fontsize=14)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, wspace=0.3)

dfSPSSactive['Q7_12_1'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(ax=axs[0], kind='bar')
dfSPSSactive['Q7_12_2'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(ax=axs[1], kind='bar', color='red')

plt.show()
```

[image]